# Purpose of automatic properties in .NET

Tags: .net, properties, automatic-properties

Why is this:

```
    public string Foo {get;set;}
```

considered better than this:

```
    public string Foo;
```

I can't for the life of me work it out. Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Comment: As always when this topic pops up, read Jon Skeet's > **[Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you can transparently (from client code's perspective) change the implementation of the setter/getter wheras you cannot do the same, if you expose the underlying property directly (as it would not be binary compatible.)

There is a certain code smell associated with automatic properties, though, in that they make it far to easy to expose some part of your class' state without a second thought. This has befallen Java as well, where in many projects you find `get/setXxx` pairs all over the place exposing internal state (often without any need for it, "just in case"), which renders the properties essentially public.

Comment: This is the answer - if you want to change the way Foo is calculated or stored you can do it transparently.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't transparently change from direct field access to a property. Client code would still use myObject.Foo = bar or Console.Write(myObject.Foo). No changes to client code...

Comment: @David: Want to bet? a) it's definitely not binary compatible, so you'd *at least* need to recompile. b) It's not source compatible in some situations - for example, you can use a field as an argument for an out parameter, but you can't use a property. Then there's anything using reflection (like data binding). Just say no to public fields...

Comment: Thanks guys. I read the article linked by 0xA3. Some of the distinctions seem a little obscure (at least for the kind of code I write), but I can see the benefit. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

While the purpose of a *field* is object state **storage**, the purpose of a *property* is merely **access**. The difference may be more conceptual than practical, but automatic properties provides a handy syntax for declaring both.